# Update Entity Framework with detached POCO object in DbContext CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have a view where I modify a "complex" object meaning it has collections of other objects, you know the usual thing:

```
[Table("Customer")]
public class Customer 
{
    [Key, Column("IdCustomer")]
    public int IdCustomer {get; set;}

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set;}

    [Column("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set;}

    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

[Table("Order")]
public class Order 
{
    [Key, Column("IdOrder")]
    public int IdOrder {get; set;}

    [Column("Quantity")]
    public int Quantity {get; set;}

    [Column("Amount")]
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}

    [Column("IdCustomer"), ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The "Customer" is an existing object in the database and it may be modified buit also it´s orders too on this said view. Once the user is ready and made his/her modifications I send a serialized full POCO object as JSON by ajax to my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ContentResult Save(Customer customer) { 
    //saving code
}
```

Now, the object that is received is just a plain object not being tracked by DbContex. This is automatically serialized from the json sent from the view JS by MVC3, but I do know and make sure that it has the same structure as the EF class it represents.

What I would like to know is: is it possible to save the whole object and its related objects modifications without actually recursing the whole thing?

E.g.

An existing customer had 3 orders, 1 was removed, another changed its data and a new one was added so I ended up with:

1. Customer.Order1 (untouched, existing)
2. Customer.Order2 (deleted)
3. Customer.Order3 (modified, existing)
4. Customer.Order4 (new, non-existing yet in db)

So instead of retrieving the original EF object and then checking each of its orders to check which one changed, which ones were removed and which ones are actually new ones, have a way to just assign this POCO object received by AJAX to the DbContext so the object graph actually checks for it by its tracker capabilities and make the needed changes.

I already followed several approaches:

**First:** If I just attach this object to the context and then change it´s DbEntry state to modified only the Customer properties are persisted in database, no Order(s) object(s) is(are) persisted since they are tracked as unchanged by SaveChanges unless I modify their state also manually.

**Second:** Loading in the controller the original entry (which makes DbContext automatically aware of the original record) and try to set values with Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues would only set the values for Customer properties but not changes in Orders collection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can vote for improved support for working with disconnected entities here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864. And there is a link there to a 3rd party tool named GraphDiff that might work for you

Comment: Thanks @Colin at the end I ended up doing it manually since I found no way to do it like that.